# Double Slider Strategy For Programming Age Range Functionality (like Tinder)

Tags: objective-c, swift, uislider, tinder

Tinder has a "double slider" feature on their app when you select an age range. It's rather nifty. I thought perhaps there would be a hack for such a thing where you could overlay two UISliders on top of each other to create this, but this doesn't work (the one in front covers up one in back, preventing touches..., and not to mention covering it) Also the line of the UISlider covers up the second UISlider; it's quite a headache. How would you guys do it? Write it from scratch?

For a picture of this functionality see: https://www.google.com/search?q=tinder+age+range&espv=2&biw=960&bih=498&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUw7nl1v_MAhVgVWMKHbyRDyIQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=hwVRxHkN5NxKEM%3A'

Edit: I think this Github link may be the way to go:
https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider

Comment: I would first try to find an open source component (such as NMRange) and then only as a fallback write something yourself. At StackOverflow those recommendations are off topic but if you have trouble implementing we're happy to help

Comment: Colin Eberhardt wrote a UIControl tutorial that uses such a slider as an example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control